# Помогите разобраться с наследованием

Tags: java, наследование

Не понимаю принцип работы `upcast`.

```
class Bird
{
    int age = 2;

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Any ways");
    }
}

class Strauss extends Bird 
{
    int age=3;

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Run "+age);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Bird s = new Strauss();
        s.move();//Run 3
        System.out.println(s.age)//2
    }
}
```

Собственно, вопрос. Почему `s.age = 2` (Берет от `Bird`), но если использовать эту переменную в методе `move()` класса `Strauss`, то она подтягивает `age` от `Strauss` и в итоге получается `"Run 3"`.

Как-то глупо вопрос задал. В общем, если вызывать `age` напрямую - то `"2"`, если через метод - то `"3"`. Почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наследование распространяется на методы, но не членов класса - у вас по сути два члена класса `Bird.age` и `Strauss.age`, которые перекрывают друг друга. Если бы вы сделали так:

```
class Bird
{
    public int age = 2; //по хорошему надо protected

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Any ways");
    }
}

class Strauss extends Bird 
{
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Run "+age);
    }
}
```

то ответ в обоих случаях был бы один и тот же.