# Не могу понять, как работает код (простенький тест на джуна по джаве)

Tags: java, наследование

```
class Base {
    public String name = "Base";
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
public class Sub extends Base {
    public String name = "Sub";
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub s = new Sub();
        Base b = s;
        System.out.println(s.name + "" + b.name);
        System.out.println(s.getName() + "" + b.getName());
    }
}
```

Вывод получается такой

```
SubBase
SubSub
```

Почему результат отличается?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите разобраться с наследованием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933226/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java по умолчанию все не приватные методы в экземплярах класса являются виртуальными, такие методы могут быть переопределены в иерархии классов, это означает, что компилятор в момент компиляции не знает какой конкретно метод должен быть вызван:

```
Base b;
if (isOdd()){
    b = new Sub();
} else {
    b = new Base();
}
b.getName() // Компилятор не знает будет ли это метод из Base или Sub
```

В этом случае нужно найти адрес вызываемого метода в момент исполнения, выполнить так называемое "позднее связывание". Это достигается посредством таблицы виртуальных методов которая хранит адреса методов. На поля класса данный механизм не распространятся, их нельзя переопределить, если все-таки создать два не приватных поля на разных уровнях иерархии с одним именем, то одно поле будет скрывать другое, но не переопределять:

```
b.name       // Всегда "Base" вне зависимости от результата isOdd()
((S) b).name // Если isOdd() == true то "Sub", иначе ClassCastException из-за попытки приведения типа.
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение!

Answer (score 0):

Метод getName в Sub является переопределенным. Поэтому вызывается метод b.getName() именно из Sub и выдает переменную name, которая хранится в Sub. А когда вы обращаетесь к переменной через b.name, то обращаетесь к переменной в Base, так как переменную нельзя переопределить.